# ImageView anchored between AppBarLayout and fragment doesn't scroll off the screen

Tags: android, material-design

I am using the Material Design Support Library and want the *movie_poster* ImageView anchored to the CollapsingToolbar. But when I scroll, the movie poster stays anchored till the top and then gets stuck at the top. How can I make it so that the poster stays with the fragment and moves out of the screen with the fragment?

The root element of the fragment is a NestedScrollView.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_backdrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            style="@style/ToolBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment android:id="@+id/movie_fragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:name="com.centerstage.limelight.MovieFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```